# If I have a button click event and an ObjectDataSource selecting event, which fires first and why?

Tags: c#, asp.net, events

Title explains it all really, which event fires first in the page life cycle and why?

Comment: A debugger can tell you in 5 seconds, but I'll bet on the Button firing last.

Comment: Actually, the button fires first! I have no idea why though...

Comment: Well, maybe you want to do some stuff on button click before selecting the entire object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this image: http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/dynimg/IC386473.png

The third column in the image shows the Control Changed events (in yellow bubble) fire before the DataBinding events.  The Selecting event is a databinding event, so it gets fire after the button click.